# Put tick labels of only x-axis inside plotting area

Tags: r, plot

Is it possible to put tick labels of only x-axis inside plotting area?
I am trying:

```
axis(1,at=c(0:71),c(rep(0:23,3)),cex.axis=.7, font=1,tck=.01)
```

It seems that:

```
par(mgp=c(0,-1.4, 0))
```

puts both `x` and `y` tick labels inside plotting area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just draw the ticks where you want them using the `pos` argument to `axis()`:

```
plot(0:72, xaxt="n")
text(0:71, -1, rep(0:23, 3), cex = 0.5)
axis(1, at=c(0:71), NA, cex.axis=.7, font=1, tck=.01)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the best and easy solution is the parameter `tcl` in `axis` or `par`.
Positive values put the marks inside, negative outside, the value is the length.
Your example:

```
axis(1,at=c(0:71),c(rep(0:23,3)),cex.axis=.7, font=1,tcl=0.3)
```